# Overwriting the existing file in wp8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

i am making an app in which i want to overwrite my file , like i am writing a number in the file and reading but the next time i want to add the new number to the existing file then read it

for writing into the file i am using the code

```
private async void cross_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{


    byte[] fileBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(this.ScoreTB.Text.ToCharArray());

    StorageFolder local = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

    var dataFolder = await local.CreateFolderAsync("MyFolder", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

    var file = await dataFolder.CreateFileAsync("MyFile.txt", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

    using (var s = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
    {
        s.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
    }
}
```

and for reading the file

```
private async void aboutus_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StorageFolder local = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

    if (local != null)
    {
        // Get the DataFolder folder.
        var dataFolder = await local.GetFolderAsync("MyFolder");

        // Get the file.
        var file = await dataFolder.OpenStreamForReadAsync("MyFile.txt");

        // Read the data.
        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(file))
        {
            this.Score.Text = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No File Created");
    }
}
```

just help me how to overwrite a existing file in windows phone app development.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the problem with your current code? looks like it already do the job, `CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting` will overwrite existing file, isn't it?

Comment: see i am making a small game in which a number comes out every time, suppose if 80 comes on 1st time i am able to write in the file now next time 20 comes so i want that the file should take 80+20 and when i read the file it should give me the result 100. but by this code i am getting 20 it is overwriting but i want that it should add to the previous number

Comment: why don't you use the IsolatedStorageSettings [link] (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings(v=vs.95).aspx)?  its just a Dictionary, where you can save the key and value

Comment: ok, that clarifies the problem. It sounds more like *append to existing file* instead of *overwrite*. Try @crea7or answer to do that, it looks promising (haven't tried it my self).

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you don't need an overwrite, but append.

1) change `ReplaceExisting` to `OpenIfExists`:

```
  var file = await dataFolder.CreateFileAsync("MyFile.txt", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists );
```

2) seek to the end of the stream before write:

```
  using (var s = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
  {
    s.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End );
    s.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
  }
```