# How to write text for exist txt file in windows app store

Tags: c#, windows-8

I want to write a string to file.txt, but it exist ready. I read at  [How to write txt file in windows app store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22551575/how-to-write-txt-file-in-windows-app-store) 
so, i don't create a file by "CreateFileAsync". i want to replace on file.txt. Help me!

Comment: i read it, but i want  to replace text on exist file, don't create a new file. @Kelix

Comment: So use `CreateFileAsync(..., CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting)`...

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("MyFile.txt", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
using (var s = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
{ s.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length); }
```

You're looking for the [`CreateCollisionOption`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br227250.aspx).
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21990670/overwriting-the-existing-file-in-wp8) for a similar question about overwriting/appending files,